# Specify path to java properties path at runtime

Tags: java, python, service, properties, subprocess

I apologize in advance if this has been answered already, but I'm unable to find anything specifically relating to this. I have a python program that launches a subprocess, at runtime, which calls a java jar file. The command looks like this:

```
# Build command line expression.
expr = self.cmmTool + " " + self.cmmIpAddress + " " + self.cmmUsername + " " + self.cmmPassword + " " + cmd + " > " + self.cmmOutputFile

# Execute command line expression.
p = subprocess.Popen(expr, shell=True)
```

If I launch my python program from a command line, all is well. An important note is that the jar file will create a SMCIPMITool.properties in the same path as the jar file. My problem is that I want to run my python program as a service. When I start the service, the python program executes fine, but has a problem with this call. My python program catches this and the program does not crash, so it will repeatedly try to execute this. The output from the java file goes into the  file specified above and looks like this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./SMCIPMITool.properties (Permission denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./SMCIPMITool.properties (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./SMCIPMITool.properties (Permission denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./SMCIPMITool.properties (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./SMCIPMITool.properties (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./SMCIPMITool.properties (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./SMCIPMITool.properties (Permission denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./SMCIPMITool.properties (Permission denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./SMCIPMITool.properties (No such file or directory)
```

Bear in mind, this is not my jar file (precompiled by super micro), so I have no control over the java code. It seems the java file, running in "service land", is either trying to write the .properties file in a location it doesn't have write access to, and/or can't find the .properties file. Also to note, the jar and .properties file both exist in the same directory. It seems when the jar file is executed in "service land" it's perhaps not actually being executed in the directory where the jar file is located.

Is it possible to specify the path to the .properties file explicitly when I call java -jar? Is there a way to set the default path to .properies files in JRE somehow? I'm a bit at a loss for next steps and google isn't helping. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edited with copy paste of actual code. The cmmTool variable contains /path/to/jar/jarFile

Comment: I'm assuming you just forgot the quotes around your `expr="..."`, yes?

Comment: You could try using `"SMCIPMITool.jar"` instead of the `'/path/to/jar/'` and call `subprocess.Popen(expr, cwd='/path/to/jar', shell=True)` and it might affect the location that the service creates or writes the file.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I rewrote my python code on the fly for this question. The python code works fine. As I said, I've run it many times launching it from the command line without problems. I will try your recommendation of cwd and report back.

Comment: Then paste the working python code. SO users are generally quite skilled, you will not fool them with pseudo code :p

Comment: Updated to get rid of 'pseudo code' thought I think it may have been more clear. Ryan's suggestion of using cwd='path/to/jar' didn't work. Same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Needed to change my service run path to be in a location where both the jar file and .properties file are. It seems that when I was launching the jar file before, it was actually being executed in a different location than where the file was located. Therefore it was unable to locate the .properties file in the same directory. Here is what my /etc/init/myservice.conf looks like (the important part anyways...earlier parts of the .conf have some stuff I shouldn't share):

```
chdir /svbase/
expect fork

script
    exec /usr/bin/python /svbase/smapp/Main.py /svbase/config/product/smapp.xml &
end script
```

That first line was necessary to change the run location of the service to where the jar file and .properties file were located.